# How to use "word-wrap:break-word" for a div without specifying width

Tags: html, css

I have to wrap the text in a div which has the width property set to auto.

I have to take the input from users and have to display it. Sometimes users are inputting data without spaces. Normal strings are wrapping fine so far without any styles. But long strings without spaces are overflowing from the container.
Here I want to use the "word-wrap:break-word;" to wrap the text. But it is working when specifying the specific width to the div. But when I specify width my layout is corrupting across the browsers.

Is there any solution to use word-wrap without specifying width property (It should work in all the browsers) ?

Comment: It's work for me with `word-wrap:break-word;text-align: justify;` in FF.

Comment: I tried with "word-break:break-word;" (Note: it is not a standard CSS spec), it is working fine with Chrome and Safari. But not useful in Firefox & IE. Is there any workaround for this in FF & IE ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I did small change in my layout which given a standard result across all the browsers.

1. Added a table inside my div (Here my table will have only one row & one column).
2. Given the following styles to the table - "*table-layout: fixed;width: 100%;word-wrap: break-word;*"

Now user input will go into the table & it wraps the small words, breaks the long words if they are overflowing from the container.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle? I'm unable to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: This is a really great solution. Basically, what it comes down to, is that some of the fluid containers (such as div and span) will not word-break when you're using a fluid layout with `width:100%;` for example. But encapsulating the things that need to be broken, with a table div with the above CSS - fixes it~

Answer (score 20):

Here is another version of using table:

```
<div class="break-word-container">
    very_long_word_without_spaces
</div>
```

and here are the styles:

```
.break-word-container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: this should be the marked answer, it's styling the element to behave like the OPs solution as opposed to adding superfluous mark up  - good work Tomasz

Answer (score 3):

I use the following styles for my web applications and they work fine in different browsers.

```
.longText {
word-break: break-all;
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;  /* CSS 2.1 */
white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3 */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
}

.longTextWrapper td {
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Hope it would help you as well.

```
  <fieldset style="overflow: auto;width:100%">  
   <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="longTextWrapper ">
     <h:outputText styleClass="longText" value="this is a very long messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee...."  />
   </h:panelGrid>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Here word-break:break-all; breaking all the words irrespective of long words. I have to wrap the small words and break the long words.

Answer (score 1):

use `overflow-wrap: break-word;`  it'll work for further reference u can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

Comment: It doesn't work if you don't specify the width of your div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "div{word-wrap:break-word; width:auto; display:inline;}".
It will break the work if there is not enough space. It will work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For my case the below css did the job instead of word-wrap

```
word-break: break-word;
width: auto;
```